# Where is an online collection of Jewish adages?

Tags: product-recommendation, internet, aphorisms-adages

> **Is there a free, online collection or compendium of Jewish aphorisms or adages?**

- If so, please provide a link.
- By "aphorism or adage," I mean a single-sentence expression of a key life truth, value or kernel of wisdom.
- I'm looking for a style [similar to this](http://www.sacred-texts.com/jud/wois/index.htm). Except for aphorisms, not parables.

Comment: Have you looked at the Book of Proverbs?

Comment: ... [Chapter 1](http://www.mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt2801.htm), with links to the rest. Why not post an answer, @DoubleAA?

Comment: This Dictionary has some great ones in the back https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/shopping?q=tbn:ANd9GcTfXYbb1SKFb6jWxl-yLqHFs2bSJK8khZ-Zn6lH9YvTdp6YmxAxugCpVU2RNvBgnpiDYrYBels&usqp=CAE

Comment: +1 and a "Favorite". Your link is quite nice! I may refer that one to others, esp. beginners. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [this page from thinkexist.com](http://thinkexist.com/quotes/Hebrew_Proverb/) It has an assortment of quotes and proverbs, many from the Talmud from different sources.

(Kudos to my shul's web site (left anonymous) for telling me about this link.)

Answer (score 4):

[This](http://m.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/5708/jewish/Translated-Text.htm) is a link to an English translation of Pirkei Avot (Teachings of Our Fathers). Pirkei Avot is one of the texts that is widely studied and it seems to meet your requirements.

Comment: Agreed. This is probably one of the most notable ones. You can find additional adages in the back of the Birnbaum Sabbath & Festival prayer book. Although, the majority of the sayings, there, are from *Pirkei Avot*, anyway. CC @Mowzer.